# Pusher Echo is not returning response in multiple blade files

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

I'm using pusher for my chat app. I have a scenario of two different users both users have a different `.blade.html` file.

Pusher is working fine and returning responses with the first user's view file but not working with the second user's view file. I've initialized this code below in the `resource/app.js` file and also run the `npm run watch`

`` Echo.private(`chat`).listen('.message', (e)=>{ console.log(e); }); ``

However other things are working fine with the second user's view like I try to use `console.log("hello");` in `resource/app.js`. It was working fine but the `Echo.private` is not working in the second file.

Please guide me I don't know what's wrong with this.